# Salesforce Extension Pack Not Working in VS Code

Tags: vs-code

I have a co-worker that installed the Salesforce Extension Pack for VS Code.  There is no go to definition for apex code and it is not possible to run tests.  We have tried uninstalling all extensions and re-installing the Salesforce extension but it still does not work.  He had also accidentally installed the Force.com extension as well.  There is no error message.  It hangs when installing the Salesforce CLI Integration and also the Apex extension.

Is there some sort of extension cache that I can clear?

Comment: Did he install the actual DX CLI tool?
https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli

Comment: Install cli then install visual studio then install the pack it should work if you have proxy setting you need to configure that

Comment: Installing Java did the trick for me as well, the problem was not in installing the extensions but they didn't work for the most part. See https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/vscode-desktop/install

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that the Salesforce Extension Pack requires Java to be installed.  I already had Java installed from a previous project and my co-worker did not.

Answer (score 0):

Error while installing 'Salesforce Extension Pack' extension. Please check the log for more details. still i am facing this issue how to solved it

Comment: Please start another question and feel free to link the old answer, maybe they did not write it well enough to get an answer, but you should not ask a question from the answers section, build some reputation and then you can comment.